# Why does my mosfet driver change frequecy

Tags: mosfet, switching, mosfet-driver

I'm having a problem with my mosfet driver which is **(HCPL-314J)** I’m using it to control my p-channel mosfet which is **IRF5210** The problem is that output frequency goes up to 200 kHz when my input frequency is about 60 kHz only. Can anyone explain why did this happen?

Here is the schematic:
[image]

Comment: Show schematic.

Comment: You took a really long shoot here asking this question without any schematic....

Comment: If I'd ask you: "when I walk around my left foot gets twisted, do you know why?", would you know what to answer? The way you couldn't read my mind to know what I am saying, the same way noone here can read minds.

Comment: Try checking your feedback/compensation network in case you're using this in some fedback switcher thing. There's really no way we can help you without a schematic.

Comment: sorry for my unclear question...i've updated it now

Comment: Still unclear.  There is no power to the arduino, so obviously it can't work.  None of the resistor values are shown.  You say FET driver in the text, but the schematic shows a opto-coupler.  What voltage is Vcc?  What voltage is D1? L1? C1? The output pins of the opto are unclear. You should be able to see for yourself that much necessary information is missing. Show scope traces of what you are driving the FET with and what the result is.  The one thing we can see is that the FET is backwards.

Comment: How are you measuring the alleged frequency???  Have you verfied the input by the same method?  Include scope plots in your question.

Comment: is there anymore missing to my schematic? pls i need help

Comment: i have measured the input frequency on the pin D9 of the controller which i get a frequency of 60KHZ and i measured the output frequency on the gate of the mosfet which i get a frequency of 200KHZ

Comment: _HOW_ did you measure? Show oscillograms.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you need to fix/check before getting into frequencies.

1. Source and drain of the MOSFET are flipped - a very common mistake. As a result the MOSFET is always conducting - not switching on and off.
2. Check the driver pinout: pins 6 and 7 are potentially flipped.
3. The driver needs a bypass capacitor - the lack of it could cause all kinds of issues.
4. Unless VCC exceeds the maximum driver supply voltage (35V), you don't need the resistor-Zener voltage limiter. If VCC is greater than 35V and you want to limit it, you have to make sure it is not creating an excessive voltage ripple on the VCC pin of the driver. Again, a capacitor at the VCC pin would help.

NOTE: In this case, you'll also need to reduce the voltage drop between the source and the gate, which will exceed maximum 20V, when the driver pulls the gate to ground. You can do it by inserting a resistor between the output of the driver and the gate and thus creating a divider. I'd suggest though that you start with a low VCC voltage, 10-15V, and, when the circuit works as expected, increase the voltage (if that's what you need), and add all necessary protections.